# Why does Realm throw an exception when querying for `size == 4`?

Tags: ios, database, realm

My subclasses of `RLMObject` look like so:

```
@interface ImageRealm : RLMObject

@property NSString *httpsURL;
@property NSNumber<RLMInt> *size;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ImageRealm)

@interface PhotoRealm : RLMObject

@property NSNumber<RLMInt> *photoID;
@property RLMArray<ImageRealm *><ImageRealm> *differentSizeImages;  

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(PhotoModel *)photoModel;

@end
```

I want to filter `PhotoRealm`'s `differentSizeImages` array to retrieve a specific `ImageRealm`. I tried with the following code:

```
PhotoRealm *photo = self.array[indexPath.row];
NSString *filter = @"size == 4";
ImageRealm *pecificImage = [[photo.differentSizeImages objectsWhere:filter] firstObject];
```

Where `self.array` is was initialized like this:

```
self.array = [PhotoRealm allObjects];
```

The code throws an exception:

> 2017-03-24 03:33:36.891 project_name[46277:3636358] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate expressions', reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'

---

**Update:** 
Before I added the `size` property I was able to do the following (since I only had one image size):

```
ImageRealm *image = [photo.differentSizeImages objectAtIndex:0];
```

But now that I've added the `size` property I need to filter the array to select the correct size image.

See the following images for an idea of the data in my Realm file:

[image: Photo]

[[image: differentSizeImgae[2]]

---

And, I noticed the example queries [in Realm's official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#filtering):

```
// Query using a predicate string
RLMResults<Dog *> *tanDogs = [Dog objectsWhere:@"color = 'tan' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'"];

// Query using an NSPredicate
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color = %@ AND name BEGINSWITH %@",
                                                     @"tan", @"B"];
tanDogs = [Dog objectsWithPredicate:pred];
```

These look the same as what I'm doing, so why am I seeing an exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When attempting to use the predicate format string `size == 4`, you're seeing an exception like so:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate expressions', reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'

The reason for this is that [`size` is a reserved word in `NSPredicate`'s format syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-213522). You can escape reserved words by prefixing them with the `#` character, so your query would become `#size == 4`

Comment: If nobody tells this trick, I think I must be confused for a long time : -)

Comment: I had the same issue with my ID fields!